# How to close clickable popup to continue scraping through Selenium in python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I'm trying to scrape some information from clickable popups in a table on a website into a `pandas` dataframe using `Selenium` in `python` and it seems to be able to do this if the popups have information.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait    
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select
import pandas as pd
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://mspotrace.org.my/Sccs_list')
time.sleep(20)

# Select maximum number of entries
elem = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('select[name=dTable_length]')
select = Select(elem)
select.select_by_value('500')
time.sleep(15)

# Get list of elements
elements = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//a[@title='View on Map']")))

# Loop through element popups and pull details of facilities into DF
pos = 0
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['facility_name','other_details'])

try:
    for element in elements:
        data = []
        element.click()
        time.sleep(3)
        facility_name = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//h4[@class="modal-title"]').text
        other_details = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="modal-body"]').text
        data.append(facility_name)
        data.append(other_details)
        df.loc[pos] = data
        WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button[aria-label='Close'] > span"))).click() # close popup window
        time.sleep(10)
        pos+=1
except:
    print("No geo location information")
    pass

print(df)
```

However, there are cases when a window like below appears and I need to click 'OK' on this to resume scraping the other rows on the web page but I can't seem to be able to find the element to click on to do this.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

can you try for Pythonenter code here:

```
driver.switch_to.alert.accept()
```

But, your test scenario should be clear and should know where this pop up appears. If you don't know and "really" random, you can check some hooks that running for each test step

Answer (score 0):

Selenium driver provides methods to switch to alerts context and working with it:

```
driver.switch_to().alert()
```

After that, you can do whatever you want, depending on alert type. To simulate clicking on “OK”:

```
driver.switch_to().alert().accept()
```

More info [here](https://www.browserstack.com/guide/alerts-and-popups-in-selenium)

Comment: thanks! this works but it looks like I had to use `driver.switch_to.alert()` instead of `driver.switchTo().alert()`. Do you know where I can include this to keep the loop continuing? It seems to stop once the alert closes.